# ms sql stored procedure return data without output

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

Hey all i am trying to find examples of getting data back from a stored procedure that has no parameters sent to it nor has any returned output parameter. Though it does display data.

How can i get that from my code im using below?

```
Dim myCommandSQL As New SqlCommand
    Dim myReaderSQL As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Dim intX As Integer = 0
    Dim connSql As SqlConnection

    Try
        connSql = New SqlConnection("Server=sqlprod;" & _
                                    "Database=ISS3_PROD;" & _
                                    "User ID=xxx;" & _
                                    "Password=xxx;" & _
                                    "Trusted_Connection=False;")
        connSql.Open()

        myCommandSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCommandSQL.CommandText = "Select_Prod"

        Dim sqlParReturn1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = myCommandSQL.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.VarChar)

        sqlParReturn1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        myCommandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox(sqlParReturn1)

        connSql.Close()
        myCommandSQL.Dispose()
```

The @return_value i just put there to see what would happen but i got nothing returned.

Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign a parameter to your command, then your stored procedure should take a parameter. Furthermore, if you specify the direction as `Output`, then you should mark that parameter as `OUTPUT` in your stored procedure.

If you just want the results of a stored procedure that doesn't take any parameters, then remove all the lines that include `sqlParReturn1`. Also, your command isn't a "non-query" -- you **are** querying for data. To get it, you should do this (I also refactored your code using some better-practice techniques):

```
Using connSql As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...)
    connSql.Open()
    Using myCommandSQL As SqlCommand = connSql.CreateCommand()
        myCommandSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCommandSQL.CommandText = "Select_Prod"
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = myCommandSQL.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read()
                    // loops through the rows returned
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
 End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx#Y0) on reading data using an ADO datareader. I think their example explains this quite well, so I have just copy and pasted the example here. Just replace your SQL setup, and then you just need to call the `ExecuteReader`, followed by a while loop that runs while `reader.Read` finds rows. Just inside the loop, you can then access your columns via `reader.Get...`, using ordinals or columnnames.

```
Private Sub HasRows(ByVal connection As SqlConnection)
    Using connection
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;", _
          connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            Do While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) _
                  & vbTab & reader.GetString(1))
            Loop
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
        End If

        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```